# Writing data to database security question

Tags: c#, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication, firebase-security

I am deving an android app, and i am planning to release it to Google Store when ready.
In this app players have balances, i am using Firebase Realtime Database as my database at the moment, which has been serving me well.

I am just wondering that how easily can this kind of code be exploited? Lets see an example:

Here is a really simple write to a user's balance section in Firebase database:

Code (CSharp):

```
dbreference.Child("Players").Child("someplayername").Child("Balance").SetValueAsync(2000);
```

How bad is this code in terms of security? Can someone "dig in" to this .apk app and simply edit that to a value of their own? I know i could do this balance add in the back end, but still there has to be SOME value sent from the users client, even if it was a simple ON/OFF boolean, and the back end would handle the rest...

Comment: Your code would never contain the string "someplayername" as that would involve creating a new APK for each player.  "someplayername" should be a unique value assigned to that user when the account is created (probably a guid or some other non-guessable number, definitely not an integer from 0-2B).

Comment: hey, thanks for this, i know, it was just an example code i wrote for this thread.